# Getting worse performance when training a pre-trained model with the existing class

Tags: neural-networks, machine-learning, deep-learning, tensorflow, object-recognition

I am training [pre-trained SSD-InceptionV2-Coco](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/detection_model_zoo.md) to detect the "car",

which is one of the classes in [mscoco label](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/data/mscoco_label_map.pbtxt).

I train the model with ~50k sample from KITTI, 500k iteration with batch size 2.

I followed [this script](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/dataset_tools/create_kitti_tf_record.py) to generate tfrecord file.

Then I test both original pre-trained model and my trained model with one video.

The performance of my trained model is worse. More missing detected results.

One thing I found recently is the classification_loss/localization_loss increases when AvgNumGroundtruthBoxesPerImage increases.

[image]

[image]

**EDIT**

[image]

Another thing I found is the more ground truth boxes per image I have,

the less average num positive anchors per image I have.

This bothers me because if the number of anchors generated per image is fixed,

more ground truth boxes should provide more positive anchors per image.

So I wonder where to find the root cause.

Any suggestion is welcome.

Thank you for precious time on my question.